# Consolidation of excel files workbooks in a folder

Tags: python, excel

I am a python beginner and I try to build a script which consolidates all existing excel workbooks into a new one in the same folder... However I have an error stating that the excel files could not be found.... I am stuck. see below the coding :

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
path = r"/Users/lb/Desktop/consolidation"
suffix = "xlsx"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirs:
    if file.endswith(suffix):
    w = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    w.Sheets(1).Copy(wb.Sheets(1))

wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(path, "result.xlsx"))
excel.Application.Quit()
```

This is the error when I run the script :

> File "C:/Users/lb/PycharmProjects/New Project/fusion2.py", line 12, in              
>       w = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
>     File "C:\Users\lb\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
>       , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "'business_Descriptor.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: It would also be good if you copy the complete error and post it with your answer in the future. The error messages will usually tell you what line in your code went wrong.

Comment: The addition of your error message makes it easier to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your path may be wrong. Usually speaking, the users directory in Windows should go something like this:

`C:\\Users\\lb\\Desktop\\consolidation`

If you are unsure about your paths, you can also debug your path by navigating through it in your python script until you find your folder with the os.chdir() command, and os.listdir() command. When you're at the folder you want, you can then use the os.getcwd() command.

[image]

I also recommend [this](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/file-interaction.html) reading if you want to get familiar with filesystems in python.

Continuing on from the previous part, it seems that in your code,

```
for file in dirs:
    if file.endswith(suffix):
        w = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
        w.Sheets(1).Copy(wb.Sheets(1))
```

You're trying to open the file with the string name of the file itself, not the path. If you take a look at the snippet below from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683517/loop-through-folder-in-python-and-open-files-throws-an-error) you'll see that they append the name with the path directory. This should fix your issue :P

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('path/to/dir'):
    if filename.endswith('.log'):
        with open(os.path.join('path/to/dir', filename)) as f:
            content = f.read()
```

Essentially what you need to do is change your

`w = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)`->
`w = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(path,file))`

So the final result of that part of your code should look like this (**Note the indentations at the if! Without them the if statement does nothing**):

```
for file in dirs:
    if file.endswith(suffix):
        w = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(path,file))
        w.Sheets(1).Copy(wb.Sheets(1))
```

Comment: @lb2019 did it work? If it worked, please mark the answer so that people can know that your question has been resolved :)

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( ... But I have added the error comments above...  It seems not related to the path ( as I have added "r" before the path in order to avoid errors...) Also, it seems python goes to the right folder and start detecting excel workbooks inside it (like Business _descriptors.xlsx). But it goes not further...  any clue ? :-(

Comment: @lb2019, yes, it actually helped. I was editing and added a part to my answer. Your loop only uses the 'filename' of the file, but doesn't give the whole **path** to excel.Workbooks.open(). So it tries to open "Business.xlsx", but it can't find it. It needs path+filename -> ("C:\\Users\\lb\\Desktop\\consolidation\\Business.xlsx")

Comment: @lb2019 Great! Glad it could help you :)

Comment: @lb2019 Oh, and don't forget to mark this answer as 'accepted' so that others can see that your question has been resolved

Comment: @lb2019, great, your first question that's been answered on SO :). Hope SO continues to be helpful for you in the future :D