# How Can You Get a File out from a Directory in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I am declaring a variable in python:

```
e = ('file.txt', 'r')
```

But the file is in a directory, and I don't know how to write it so that it will look in my directory playergold. I tried

```
playergold = 'PlayerFiles/PlayerGold'
e = open('playergold/gold.1.txt', 'r')
```

and

```
e = open(from playergold import gold.1.txt', 'r')
```

and

```
e = open(playergold/'gold.1.txt', 'r')
```

but neither works. (btw, I am getting this code from the question [Loop Through A Folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683517/loop-through-folder-in-python-and-open-files-throws-an-er))

The directory tree looks like this:

> Code contains methods.py, which is where all the code is.
>
> PlayerFiles contains the folder PlayerGold and PlayerItems
>
> PlayerGold contains gold.1.txt

PlayerFiles and Code are on the same level.

Any help would be nice. Thanks for your time!

Comment: what do you mean by *get a file out of a directory*? Do you want to parse the file? "Physically" move it?

Comment: No, I want to read and write in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
import os

with open(os.path.join('PlayerFiles','PlayerGold', 'gold.1.txt')) as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    #process
```

Comment: What does join do exactly? Do you just use it whenever folders are involved?

Comment: Would `e = open(os.path.join(playergold, 'gold.1.txt'), 'r')` work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is correct and try to pass it in correct form - always remember to open a closed quotation mark.

```
e = open('playergold/gold.1.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I forgot something. I tried that, but it gives me an error.